# When user click the radio button(Yes),then only browse button should enable using angular 6?

Tags: typescript, angular6

Using **angular 6** user clink on radio button (yes),the browse button will enable,otherwise it should be disable (Browse) **input type='file'**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit confused but I think this is what you are looking for

```html
<label>With file:</label>
<input type="radio" [checked]="enableInput" (click)="onClick()"/>
<input type="file" *ngIf="enableInput"/>
```

```js
public enableInput = false;

onClick(){
    this.enableInput = !this.enableInput;
}
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jrbewk?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: You're welcome, you should mark the question as resolved as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)